# How can I make Photoshop menus dark?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, dark-mode, app-menu

Photoshop menus are white:

[image]

Even with dark mode on:

[image]

I also use Win10 native dark mode:

[image]

How can I make Photoshop menus dark?

Comment: I think this could not be possible unless you go and change also the OS menu via theme modification, because these menus are outside photoshop ui but provided by win32 gfx libraries. You could dig inside windows themes section in control panel and try to achieve something ok for you.

Comment: @user3450548 thanks, I use Win10 native dark mode.

Comment: Not sure that's possible to be honest. Also tech support is off-topic here anyway - although other applications seem to manage dark menus just fine - such as GIMP and Inkscape.  I guess it's not on Adobe's to-do-list.

Comment: Related on Adobe Community Support: [Dark theme has white menus?](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/dark-theme-has-white-menus/td-p/10369884)

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to find something like win7 Window Color and Appearance and tweak the windows dark mode including also the menu and other parts.

[image]

Here you should be able to tweak the colors as needed.
If even this doesn't help my only idea is to tweak some undocumented registry key as usual happens in windows environment -_-'

Answer (score 0):

Reddit user [CreeDorofl](https://www.reddit.com/user/CreeDorofl) [pointed](https://redd.it/tnjswv) me to the following solution:

> It turns out photoshop respects an ancient Windows setting for customizing your window and menu colors, even though that option isn't available anymore in windows 10 or 11. You can still change the colors through the registry, or through a little freeware tool.
>
> Tool can be downloaded here: https://www.wintools.info/index.php/classic-color-panel
>
> The colors you want to change are listed as "menu" and "menutext". All the tool does really is modify certain registry settings. If you're comfortable with the registry, run regedit and navigate here (you can copy and paste this path into the nav bar up top):
>
> ```
> Computer\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Colors
> ```
>
> In the pane on the right you'll see various keys, representing UI elements that can be recolored. Most of them (seemingly) won't work because Windows 10 puts a new custom interface on top of all the old menus. But photoshop's white menu will be affected. Double click the "menu" key on the right, and change it to whatever you want. the format is RGB numbers between 0 and 255, separated by a space. Examples:
> 40 40 40 = Very dark gray.
> 255 0 0 = pure red.
> etc.
>
> You will also want to change the menu text color from black to white, or at least something light.
>
> Screenshot of the registry settings I used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHeBE.png